# elasticsearch doesn't update documents

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm facing up with a trouble related with document updatings.

I'm able to index(create) documents and they are correctly added on index.

Nevertheless, when I'm trying to update one of them, the operation is not made, the document is not updated.

When I first time add the document it's like:

```
{
        "user" : "user4",
        "timestamp" : "2016-12-16T15:00:22.645Z",
        "startTimestamp" : "2016-12-16T15:00:22.645Z",
        "dueTimestamp" : null,
        "closingTimestamp" : null,
        "matter" : "F1",
        "comment" : null,
        "status" : 0,
        "backlogStatus" : 20,
        "metainfos" : {
          "ceeaceaaaceeaceaaaceeaceaaaceeaaceaaaceeabceaaa" : [ "FZ11" ]
        },
        "resources" : [ ],
        "notes" : null
      }
```

This is the code I'm using in order to build UpdateRequest:

```
this.elasticsearchResources.getElasticsearchClient()
 .prepareUpdate()
 .setIndex(this.user.getMe().getUser())
 .setType(type)
 .setId(id.toString())
 .setDoc(source)
 .setUpsert(source)
 .setDetectNoop(true);
```

I've also been able to debug which's the content of this request begore sending it to elasticsearch. The document is:

```
{
   "user":"user4",
   "timestamp":"2016-12-16T15:00:22.645Z",
   "startTimestamp":"2016-12-16T15:00:22.645Z",
   "dueTimestamp":null,
   "closingTimestamp":null,
   "matter":"F1",
   "comment":null,
   "status":0,
   "backlogStatus":20,
   "metainfos":{

   },
   "resources":[

   ],
   "notes":null
}
```

As you can see the only difference is `metainfos` is empty when I try to update the document.

After having performed this `update request` the document is not updated. I mean the content of `metainfos` keeps as before:

```
#curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/user4/fuas/_search?pretty'
{
  "took" : 2,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "max_score" : 1.0,
    "hits" : [ {
      "_index" : "living_v1",
      "_type" : "fuas",
      "_id" : "327c9435-c394-11e6-aa90-02420a011808",
      "_score" : 1.0,
      "_routing" : "user4",
      "_source" : {
        "user" : "user4",
        "timestamp" : "2016-12-16T15:00:22.645Z",
        "startTimestamp" : "2016-12-16T15:00:22.645Z",
        "dueTimestamp" : null,
        "closingTimestamp" : null,
        "matter" : "F1",
        "comment" : null,
        "status" : 0,
        "backlogStatus" : 20,
        "metainfos" : {
>>>>>>>>    "ceeaceaaaceeaceaaaceeaceaaaceeaaceaaaceeabceaaa" : [ "FZ11" ]
        },
        "resources" : [ ],
        "notes" : null
      }
    } ]
  }
}
```

I don't quite figure out what's wrong. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ElasticSearch will not update an empty object. You can try with: 
**null** `"metainfos":null` 
or 
 `"metainfos":"ceeaceaaaceeaceaaaceeaceaaaceeaaceaaaceeabceaaa":[]`

to clean the field.

Comment: Let me dig a bit more into your answer. Nevertheless, the first time I create a document, this property `metainfos` is an empty array instead of a `null value` (`metainfos: [])`. Is it possible? (I'm not able to test it right now...)

Comment: It depends on your mapping, but yes empty array also works.

Comment: Thanks @Hosar. You have written down that `"it depends on your mapping"`. Could you detail a bit more what you mean?